# combining htaccess for multuple rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Is it possible to combine rewrite rules in an htaccess file?

My current one changes my links so that if someone enters /media it rewrites to add media.html.

I would like to add to this and have my nonwww homepage redirected to the www.

How do I add (where example.com is mywebsitename.com)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Just having them in the order shown should work.

Comment: @anubhava so like this 'code' RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htmlRewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: Keep 301 rule before `.html` adding rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clear it up, you don't need the rewrite engine on twice. You just need to add the rules in the order you listed them in to begin with.

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect nonwww to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
#remove html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Maybe this well help the confusion. Your htaccess file can contain as many rules as you need. You just have to becareful not to create any conflicts.